# Display sql xml data in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a following XML nodes in the table. But when I fetch the data I was not able to read it properly

```
SELECT Data.value('(/*//Plans/Plan/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/Entry[@key="NumberOfHoldDays"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PLANA
,Data.value('(/*//Plans/Plan/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/Entry[@key="NumberOfHoldDays"]/value)[2]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS PLANB
,Data.value('(/*//Plans/Plan/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/Entry[@key="NumberOfHoldDays"]/value)[3]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS PLANC 
FROM Maintenance
```

If I read the XML data as above when there

```
SNO    PLan A PLan B Plan C
1      11      22      33
2      NULL    44      55

Output for above example :

SNO    PLan A PLan B Plan C
1      11      22      33
2      NULL    44      55

But now for the above query it shows as below :

SNO    PLan A PLan B Plan C
1      11      22      33
2      44      55     NULL
```

Xml Sample as Follows :

```
<Plans>
  <Plan>
   <Coverages>
    <Coverage>
      <Answers>
           <Entry key="NumberOfHoldDays" type="System.String">
                <value>5</value>
              </Entry>
  </Answers>
  </Coverage>
</Coverages>
<ID>1</ID>
 </Plan>
<Plans>
  <Plan>
   <Coverages>
    <Coverage>
      <Answers>
           <Entry key="NumberOfHoldDays" type="System.String">
                <value>55</value>
              </Entry>
  </Answers>
  </Coverage>
</Coverages>
<ID>2</ID>
 </Plan>

<Plans>
  <Plan>
   <Coverages>
    <Coverage>
      <Answers>
           <Entry key="NumberOfHoldDays" type="System.String">
                <value>50</value>
              </Entry>
  </Answers>
  </Coverage>
</Coverages>
<ID>3</ID>
 </Plan>
</Plans>
```

How can I read the XML based on the ID tag to get the appropriate value I am using something like below but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works :

```
SELECT Data.value('(/*//Plans/Plan[ID="1"]/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/Entry[@key="NumberOfHoldDays"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PLANA
,Data.value('(/*//Plans/Plan[ID="2"]/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/Entry[@key="NumberOfHoldDays"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS PLANB
,Data.value('(/*//Plans/Plan[ID="3"]/Coverages/Coverage/Answers/Entry[@key="NumberOfHoldDays"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS PLANC 
FROM Maintenance
```